How to generate a drawing for this torch nn model?
I have tried a few ideas to generate a drawing of TimesNet() class in this repository:
https://github.com/xuhongzuo/DeepOD/blob/main/deepod/models/time_series/timesnet.py
but have not been successful. Can anyone help with that?
import torchvision
from torchview import draw_graph
from deepod.models.time_series import TimesNet

detector = TimesNet()
detector.fit(X_train)
model_graph = draw_graph( detector, input_data=(100, 10) , expand_nested=True)
model_graph.visual_graph

